# Determining Vector Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm not sure if I am doing these questions properly, I'd appreciate it if someone could let me know if I am, or if I am making mistakes to correct me. Determine which sets are vector spaces under the given operations.

---

$(x,y,z) + (x', y',z') = (x + x', y + y', z + z')\text{ and }k(x,y,z) = (0,0,0)$

This is a vector space, as $k(x,y,z)=0$ and the theorem that if $ku=0$, then either $k=0$, or $u=0$, then $x,y,z = 0$

---

(x,y) + (x', y') = (x + x', y + y') and k(x,y) = (2kx, 2ky)

The set of all real numbers $x$ with the standard operations of addition and multiplication.

The set of all real numbers of the form $(x,0)$ with the standard operations on $\mathbb{R}^2$

The set of all pairs of real numbers of the form $(x,y)$, where $x \geq 0$, with the standard operations on $\mathbb{R}^2$

The set of all $n$-tuples of real numbers of the form $(x,x,...,x)$ with the standard operations on $\mathbb{R}^n$

---

These are all vector spaces as well? I wasn't able to see where they failed on the axioms.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is unclear, what field of scalars are you over? What range of values can the $x,y,z$ take? What theorem do you mean? 
These questions aside this is not a vector space unless it only contains $(0,0,0)$ as it fails $1\cdot(x,y,z)=(x,y,z)$

The second is not a vector space as $(jk)\cdot(x,y)=(2jkx,2jky)\neq j\cdot(k\cdot (x,y))=(4jkx,4jky)$.

Three and four are both vector spaces but the fifth isn't as you can't scale by say $-1$.

The last one is also a vector space, indeed three, four and six are all the same vector space (we say they are isomorphic).